# Spring Social Google return after login wrong

Tags: java, google-plus, spring-social

I have implemented Spring social for Facebook, Twitter and Google.
For the first 2 it works but Google redirect the user to **/signin** after accepting on the google page where you allow my application access to your google+ account.
/signin is a 404. If I make a page for /signin the page is shown but the user is not logged in.

I am to familiar with the underlying mechanics of connectController and GoogleConnectionFactory but i believe it should redirect the request back to where it came from and with access tokens. This is /auth/google i believe. I tried a redirect from /signin to /auth/google but that did not work. As mentioned for Twitter and Facebook there was no problem.

**The code:**
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer

```
@Override
public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("facebook.app.id"),
            env.getProperty("facebook.app.secret")
    ));
    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("twitter.consumer.key"),
            env.getProperty("twitter.consumer.secret")
    ));
    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new GoogleConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("google.app.id"),
            env.getProperty("google.app.secret")));
}

@Bean
public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
.apply(getSpringSocialConfigurer()); //to http.

private SpringSocialConfigurer getSpringSocialConfigurer() {
    SpringSocialConfigurer config = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
    config.alwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true);
    config.postLoginUrl("/");

    return config;
}
```

the jsp.

```
  //facebook
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/facebook" class="hidden-xs">
                    <img src="<c:url value="/static/img/fb-login.png"/>" height="32"/>      
                </a>

//twitter
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/twitter" class="hidden-xs">
                    <img src="<c:url value="/static/img/twitter-login.png"/>" height="20" width="24"/>      
                </a>
 //google
            <form name="go_signin" id="go_signin" action="<c:url value="/auth/google"/>" method="POST" class="float-left">          
                <div onclick="this.parentNode.submit();">
                    <img src="<c:url value="/static/img/google-login.png"/>" height="32"/>      
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" /> 
            </form>
```

In the google app console i set Redirect URIs to : {my_url}/auth/google 
and Javascript Origins just to my url.
I tried almost every combination. anything but /auth/google will result in a redirect uri mismatch error before you get to the google login page

Any idea`s are welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to change the settings in the Google console for what redirect_uri is allowed but then you have to configure in your code somewhere what the redirect_uri actually should be. The documentation probably says somewhere.

Comment: I added PostLoginURL and also try to set it in the form :  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />  But it does not work. Google Docs says the following but in my case does not seem to do that : After the user authorizes your app they will be redirected to your /oauth/ url. There you will receive a "code" parameter. You can exchange that code for an access token:   This is a SpringSocialController that should handle the authentication.

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? I have the same issue. After logging for a first time the google redirects me to `/signin` instead of `/singup`.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This project has a good working sample on using spring-social-google : https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google-example

Comment: Well i was implementing this tutorial : http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/   I only need the login functionality. I looked at the source code of that project. The documentation says the sign in controller registers POST /signin/{providerId}, i get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, after logging in, there was redirection to /signin, yet it was not performed by google, but by Spring Social Google plugin. It sends  GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me, which can only be called if Google+ Api is enabled for your application in Google Console.

redirect_uri should be /auth/google

This issue was discussed in https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google/issues/22. In future release it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

updating version of spring-social-google in pom.xml to 1.0.0.RC1 solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and nothing worked after trying all solutions available on google and stack overflow. This resolved the problem for me:

1. I upgraded the Spring-boot version to "2.3.1.RELEASE" and rebuilt the application. Then added this property in application.yml (talking about google here but i think it will work for facebook, okta and other identity provider platform) :

---

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client: 
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: 'your google client id'
            clientSecret: 'your google client secret'
            redirect-uri: https://www.yourdomain.com/login/oauth2/code/google # important
```

Defining redirect-uri , did the work and that was only possible if you are working on a spring-boot 2.3.x and above release.
Don't waste your time on "redirect-uri-template" as you will be facing problem when google redirects the user-agent back to your application. Spring will still be authenticating the redirect-uri internally.

2. If you are working behind a reverse proxy (may be nginx) the this should be your server configuration :

   ```
    location / {
        absolute_redirect off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
   ```

These settings on ngnix will make sure that Spring gets requests header which are coming in the request.